# Why am I experiencing this error when publishing my application?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I created an app with npm run build and tried testing on the github page. But I have an error with the way I call the js file. I already changed the files manually in the service worker but I still can't solve it. If anyone wants to take a look, this is the [link](https://edinhorod.github.io/add-home-screen/):

My Service Worker

```js
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read 

/* eslint-disable */

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
    window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
        /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
        const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
        if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
            // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
            // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
            // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
            return;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

            if (isLocalhost) {
                // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
                checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

                // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
                // service worker/PWA documentation.
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
                    console.log(
                        'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
                        'worker. To learn more'
                    );
                });
            } else {
                // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
                registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
            }
        });
    }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
            registration.onupdatefound = () => {
                const installingWorker = registration.installing;
                if (installingWorker == null) {
                    return;
                }
                installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
                    if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                            // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
                            // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
                            // content until all client tabs are closed.
                            console.log(
                                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                                'tabs for this page are closed.'
                            );

                            // Execute callback
                            if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                                config.onUpdate(registration);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // At this point, everything has been precached.
                            // It's the perfect time to display a
                            // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                            console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

                            // Execute callback
                            if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                                config.onSuccess(registration);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
        });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
    // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
    fetch(swUrl)
        .then(response => {
            // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
            const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
            if (
                response.status === 404 ||
                (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
            ) {
                // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                    registration.unregister().then(() => {
                        window.location.reload();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
                registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(
                'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
            );
        });
}

export function unregister() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
            registration.unregister();
        });
    }
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
    console.log(e.request.url);
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(function (response) {
            return response || fetch(e.request);
        })
    );
});
```

My index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Yeapps PWA">
    <meta name="description" content="Yeapps PWA">
    <!-- Add meta theme-color -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#007bff" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/192X192.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%//icons/icon-152x152.png"> -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./icons/192X192.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./icons/icon-152x152.png">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>PWA</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>

    <button class="add-button btn btn-danger">Instalar Yeapps</button>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {
                    console.log('Worker registration successful', registration.scope);
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('Worker registration failed', err);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
        }

        let deferredPrompt;
        const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
        addBtn.style.display = 'none';
        
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
            // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
            e.preventDefault();
            // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
            deferredPrompt = e;
            // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
            addBtn.style.display = 'block';

            addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
                addBtn.style.display = 'none';
                // Show the prompt
                deferredPrompt.prompt();
                // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
                deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
                    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
                    } else {
                        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
                    }
                    deferredPrompt = null;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `service-worker.js` file in the same directory as the `.html` file corresponding to the page you're on ?

Comment: Yes, the two files are in the same directory

Comment: Some code would be helpful.